# How to retrieve a single record from Firebase Real Time Database in Xamarin-Android?

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I need to read only one entity from Firebase Realtime Database and convert the result into a C# class matching the structure, but I haven't found a solution clear. Having this tree:

```
{
 "characters" : {
    "c1" : {
      "Email" : "peter.pan@example.com",
      "LastName" : "Pan",
      "Name" : "Peter"
    },
    "c2" : {
      "Email" : "harry.potter@example.com",
      "LastName" : "Potter",
      "Name" : "Harry"
    }
  }
}
```

And this C# class:

```
public class Character 
{
   public string Email {get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to retrieve only one record by email, which I know and it is unique. But, if I do include the NuGet package [Xamarin.Firebase.Database](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Database/60.1142.1) there not exists a method or extension method such as `OnceSingle<T>() or OnceSingleAsync<T>()` in it:

```
Character character = await FirebaseDatabase.Instance
  .GetReference(CharactersRoot)
  .OrderByChild("Email")
  .EqualTo("harry.potter@example.com") //Works until here
  .OnceSingleAsync<Character>(); //THIS METHOD IS NOT AVAILABLE. It doesn't work.
```

In the other hand, by including package [Xamarin.Forms.FirebaseWrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.FirebaseWrapper/), an upgrade of the former [Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin), that supports `OnceSingleAsync<T>()` one can code something like this:

```
FirebaseClient fbClient= new FirebaseClient(Root);
var task = Task<Character>.Run(async () => 
            {
                return await fbClient.Child(CharactersRoot)
                    .OrderBy("Email")
                    .EqualTo("harry.potter@example.com")
                    .OnceSingleAsync<Character>().ConfigureAwait(false)
            });                 
            var character = task.Result;
            // do something with character...
```

But it doesn't work. It raises a **System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).)'**

The following is the only I've managed to make it work, but it is under performant because it retrieves all the collection and performs the search locally.

```
    FirebaseClient fbClient= new FirebaseClient(Root);
    var task = Task<Character>.Run(async () =>
            {
                return await fbClient.Child(CharactersRoot)                                     
                                    .OnceAsync<Character>()
                                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            });
            var character = task.Result
                            .Where(item => item.Object.Email == "harry.potter@example.com")
                            .Select(itm => itm.Object)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
            if (character != null)
            {
                //Do something with character
            }
```

Any ideas that can help to clarify my mind to do it simpler and better will be appreciated.

Comment: No one idea? I wasn't clear enough? O Am I alone trying to develop with Xamarin? Please let me know...

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to retrieve only one record by email, which I know and it is unique.

What you are looking for is a way to query the database based on certain value(Email).
Reading through the Firebase Database Doc, you can find the [Filtering Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?authuser=0#filtering_data) which explains what you want.

To meet your scenario, what you need to do is:

1. Sort your children elements based on Email and use EuqalTo() to limit the output data range.

   ```
   var db = FirebaseDatabase.Instance;
   var mDatabase = db.GetReference("characters");
   Query query = mDatabase.OrderByChild("Email")
                          .EqualTo("harry.potter@example.com");
   ```
2. Create a Child event listener to retrieve the filtered data.

   ```
   public class MyChildEventListener : Java.Lang.Object, IChildEventListener
   {
       public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
       {}

       public void OnChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, string previousChildName)
       {
           //this method will be triggered
           //snapshot's key is c2 namly harry potter
       }

       public void OnChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, string previousChildName)
       {}

       public void OnChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, string previousChildName)
       {}

       public void OnChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot)
       {}
   }
   ```
3. Register `MyChildEventListener`:

   ```
   query.AddChildEventListener(new MyChildEventListener());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<Character> GetAttendant(string email)
    {
        return (await firebase
          .Child("Character")
          .OnceAsync<Character>()).Select(item => new Character
          {
              EmailAddress = email,
          }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

//Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.