# How to show data stored in firebase RealtimeDataBase inside a new page in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, database, firebase, xamarin.forms, data-retrieval

I hava created a realTimeDatabase, in which i stored some data, such as the name of a Company.
When I click on "store data" i move into a tabbed page. So How can i visualize only the name of the company like a title of the tabbedPage?

Comment: you figured out how to save data in Firebase but can't figure out how to query it?  What have you tried?  There are lots of existing questions that address this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881101/how-to-retrieve-a-single-record-from-firebase-real-time-database-in-xamarin-andr

Comment: I saved some data, but i am unable ti visualize One of this into another Page

Comment: In particular i want to show It by xaml, It Is possibile?

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't really matter where you get the data from.  Again, there are LOTS of existing questions and documentation and samples of data binding with XAML.

Comment: Can you help me i cannot find this examples on binding on xaml

Comment: google "xamarin data binding" and this is the FIRST RESULT - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need get the data from your RealtimeDataBase,then binding it to your page,

For example:

the model **Company**:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

}
```

create **FireBaseHelp** ,operate the firabase：

```
public class FirebaseHelper
{
    FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://androiddemo-f9385.firebaseio.com/");

    public async Task<List<Company>> GetAllCompanies()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Companies")
          .OnceAsync<Company>()).Select(item => new Company
          {
              CompanyName = item.Object.CompanyName,
              CompanyId = item.Object.CompanyId
          }).ToList();
    }

    public async Task AddCompay(int companyId,string companyName)
    {

        await firebase
          .Child("Companies")
          .PostAsync(new Company() { CompanyId = companyId, CompanyName = companyName});
    }

    public async Task<Company> GetCompany(int companyId)
    {
        var allCompanies = await GetAllCompanies();
        await firebase
          .Child("Companies")
          .OnceAsync<Company>();
        return allCompanies.Where(a => a.CompanyId == companyId).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

create tabbed page **CompanyPage**:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CompanyPage : TabbedPage
{
    public CompanyPage(List<Company> allCompanies)
    {
        foreach (var item in allCompanies)
        {
            Children.Add(new MyCompanyPage(item));
        }
    }
}
```

create **MyCompanyPage.xaml.cs** ,the children of the tabbedpage (set BindingContext here to binding your data).

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyCompanyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyCompanyPage(Company company)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = company;
    }
}
```

**MyCompanyPage.xaml** ,binding the companyName as your need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Title="{Binding CompanyName}"
         x:Class="XamarinFirebase.MyCompanyPage">
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding CompanyName}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

then in MainPage,when you click a button it will query the FireBase and get the data.

```
  private async void BtnRetrive_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        var allCompanies = await firebaseHelper.GetAllCompanies();
        Navigation.PushAsync(new CompanyPage(allCompanies));
    }
```

You could read [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/) and
here is a gif for the effect(add three cpmpanies and display them in tabbedpage):

[image]

Comment: yes, when i SIGNUP i can see the companyname but when i logout, then login i cannot see any name of company. What can i do?

Comment: I think this is related to [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and have you determined some [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/index) for your `Firebase Realtime Database` ? I don't know much about it.And this is another question,you could open a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61763379/how-to-getuser-with-more-input-in-xamarin-forms i've already open

Comment: @EdoardoDellaSeta ok,i will do some researching,if I have any feedback or suggestions, I will reply to you in new questions. And if the answer is useful to you on this question, could you mark it as an accept solution?

Comment: Perfect i Mark but i am less than 15 reputation

Comment: @EdoardoDellaSeta Could you see a "✔"  to the left of the answer ?If yes,you could click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in

Comment: Done... Thank you